# java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed prob

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jdbc, thread-sleep

i have error when i try run this code

i am try many time
i try to make delay 3 second before read next value from daabase 
i have error 
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

what you think about this error because i don't now about this error

and this is my code , please help me

```
try {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://*******/jointdb";
        String dbUsr = "****";
        String dbPass = "*****";
        String sql = "select * from eridb";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUsr, dbPass);
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while ( rs.next() ) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String value = rs.getString("id");
                jTextArea1.setText(value); 
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(KK.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { }   
    finally{
        try{
           if (rs != null)
             rs.close();
           if (st != null) 
             st.close();
           if (conn != null) 
             conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){}
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You access the `ResultSet` in a different thread. By the time it's called, the original thread has finished its `try` block, moved on to the `finally`, and closed the `ResultSet`.

Comment: what you mean, please give me more hinit

Comment: i am put finally block after first try inside SwingUtilities.invokeLater thread

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Thread is a separate process in your main code. Your main code will run in parallel with your thread.

Perhaps you join the thread you create with the main code, so the main code can wait for the thread to end before it continues to close the result set. To achieve this try giving your thread a reference for example thread1  and then in main code you can add the following statement.

```
thread1.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per definition, `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` will run **asynchronously** after all AWT events are processed (documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))).

So, most probable, is that the `finally` block is reached, before the `Runnable` code inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is executed.

I see no need to execute the record processing asynchronously, I'd recommend you to read and fill the Jtextarea without detaching it from the current thread.

Comment: i am put finally block after first try inside SwingUtilities.invokeLater thread

Comment: What I'm suggesting, is that you should move the code inside the "new Runnable(){}", and move it inside the try block, and remove the "invokeLater". By the way, is there any particular reason to do that?